# Challenge of Translating Python Code to C: Implementing Luhn Algorithm for Checksum Calculation

Tags: python, c, algorithm, long-integer, luhn

I'm currently working on implementing the Luhn algorithm in C for checksum calculation. However, I encountered an issue with my C code where it consistently produces incorrect output (giving 11 instead of the expected 29). Frustrated by this, I decided to rewrite the algorithm in Python, which surprisingly worked flawlessly within just 2 minutes. I'm now puzzled about what might be causing the discrepancy between the C and Python implementations. Could someone please lend a hand in reviewing my C code and help identify the underlying issue? Below are both implementations for comparison:

```py
x = 4003600000000014

def checkSum(n):
    sm = 0
    swm = 0
    j = 10
    k = 100
    l = 100
    m = 1000
    for i in range(0, len(str(n)) // 2):
        sm += (((n % k) - (n % j)) // j)*2
        j *= 100
        k *= 100
    swm += n % 10
    for i in range(0, len(str(n)) // 2):
        swm += ((n % m) - (n % l)) // l
        l *= 100
        m *= 100
    return sm+swm

print(checkSum(x))
```

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int checkSum(long n);
int longLength(long n);

int main(void)
{
    long long number = 4003600000000014;
    printf("%d\n", checkSum(number));
    return 0;
}

int longLength(long n)
{
    int length = 0;
    while (n > 0)
    {
        n = n/10;
        length++;
    }
    return length;
}

int checkSum(long n)
{
    int sm = 0;
    int swm = 0;
    int j = 10;
    int k = 100;
    int l = 100;
    int m = 1000;

    for(int i=0;i<longLength(n)/2;i++)
    {
        sm += (((n % k)-(n % j))/j)*2;
        j *= 100;
        k *= 100;
    }
    swm+= n % 10;
    for(int i=0 ;i<longLength(n)/2;i++)
    {
        swm +=(((n % m)-(n % l))/l);
        l *= 100;
        m *= 100;
    }
    return sm + swm;
}
```

Comment: You'll make things much easier on yourself if you store the credit card number in a string rather than an integer. Then it's easy to iterate over the digits.

Comment: General rule for "translating" code: Don't do it. Take the algorithm, or the design, and reimplement it from the ground up instead.

Comment: The arguments to `longLength` and `checkSum` need to be `long long`, not `long`. The credit card number doesn't fit in a `long` so you're overflowing.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude But the translation produced working code. The problem is in the original code.

Comment: Also note that many values in your code can't be negative, so use unsigned integers instead. Or, as mentioned by @Barmar, use strings. Credit-card numbers can (IIRC) have leading zeros. C integers can't. It's the same with phone-numbers, don't use integers to store them. Not to mention that it's a *lot* easier to get each digit one by one, from the start to the end.

Comment: It's perverse to input a "number" as an integer, and then painfully convert it back to the digit string that was entered.

Comment: `checkSum` is not used in your C example. Please make sure you are transcribing your examples exactly (copy & paste).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `long` number is possibly narrower than a `long long`.

Use a wider argument in the declaration and definition to not lose information.

```
// int longLength(long n);
int longLength(long long n);
// int checkSum(long n);
int checkSum(long long n);


// int longLength(long n)
int longLength(long long n)
  ...

// int checkSum(long n) 
int checkSum(long long n)
  ...
```

---

Save time and enable **all** compiler warnings to receive something like:

```
warning: conversion from 'long long int' to 'long int' may change value [-Wconversion]
```

This will indicate many of the `int` variables should be `long long`.

```
// warning: conversion from 'long int' to 'int' may change value [-Wconversion]
sm += (((n % k) - (n % j)) / j) * 2;
```

Comment: I've did it ,and nothing changed

Comment: @AhmedSeddikBouchiba Answer updated.  Please post compiler options used.

Comment: @AhmedSeddikBouchiba The most important lesson: enable all compiler warnings

Comment: @AhmedSeddikBouchiba and the reason it's so easy in Python is that Python doesn't apply any limits to the size of integers, they expand to fit whatever number you're using.